# Speech Recognition API in Microsoft Edge (Not defined)

Tags: javascript, api, speech-recognition, microsoft-edge, speech-to-text

I have been attempting to use the SpeechRecognition API(https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#examples-recognition) in a recent project.
I am currently using the browser Microsoft edge and according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition it is only partially supported on there.
From the looks of it, it seems that the "text to speech" feature is supported (SpeechSynthesis) on Edge but not the Speech Recognition feature. As no matter what prefix I use for the SpeechRecognition (Speech to text) API in EDGE it always does not recognise it and says it "is not defined"

Anyone have any clarity on this situation, or know how to get the Speech Recognition to work with edge in JavaScript?

Cheers

Comment: It is partially supported in Edge Chromium - not the older Edge versions. Which Edge version do you have?

Comment: As far as i'm aware I have the most up to date version. I have seen it is partially supported in edge and I have the "Text to speech" api working in edge, so I assumed as the Speech to Text API wasn't working, that was one feature not yet working in edge.

Comment: Check the about page to know which version it is you have. If you don't have the Chromium version there is probably nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: Assuming you mean if I have the most up to date version then you assume there is nothing I can do? as you put if I don't have Chromium version there is nothing i can do

Comment: If you don't have Edge Chromium there is probably no way of adding support for the speech recoginition api. You can always try to find a polyfill if you want.

Comment: Ok I now have Chromium and I no longer get the "Undefined" issue. Appreciated. Yet to find out if the API will fully work but It recognises it now, cheers.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You could put your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @EthanVenencia did you have any luck getting this to work properly in Edge Chromium? I'm seeing it on the window object but it errors out as soon as you `start()`. I'm assuming some setting somewhere will enable it but no luck yet.

Comment: @LT86 No I did not get it to work on Chromium. This issue got rid of the non defined error but I was unable to find why it was not working

Comment: How does it not working? Could you please provide [a minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show how you use the SpeechRecognition API and reproduce your issue? You could open a new thread to ask the new question and put the solution of this thread in the answer.

Comment: @YuZhou I think the easiest is to use [this demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) provided by Google. From my tests the `onresult` and `onerror` event listeners never get fired

Comment: @YuZhou yes I have looked at that example many times and it works perfectly in chrome, but not in Edge.

Comment: SpeechRecognition API indeed has some issues in Edge Chromium. I've seen [other threads about this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/web-speech-api-support/m-p/1104645). I also provide feedback about the issues using SpeechRecognition API in Edge Chromium. Let's wait and see if the Edge team will fix it in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: As of 1/18/2022 the Speech Recognition part of the JavaScript Web Speech API seems to be working in Edge Chromium. Microsoft seems to be experimenting with it in Edge. It is automatically adding punctuation and there seems to be no way to disable auto punctuation. I'm not sure about all the languages it supports. But it seems to be working so far in English, Spanish, German, French, Chinese Simplified and Japanese. I'm leaving the information below for history.

As of 6/4/2020 Edge Chromium does not really support the Speech Recognition part of the Web Speech API. [Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/web-speech-api-support/m-p/1104645) seems to be working on it for Edge Chromium. It will probably never work for Edge Legacy (non-Chromium).

[developer.microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/status/webspeechapispeechrecognition/?q=speechrecognition) says incorrectly that it is "Supported" but also says, "Working draft or equivalent". (UPDATE: As of 2/18/2021 it now says: "NOT SUPPORTED")

[developer.mozilla.org compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Browser_compatibility) also incorrectly says that it is supported in Edge.

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition) correctly shows that it is not supported in Edge Chromium even though it acts like it is but the proper events are not fired.

The only other browsers besides Chrome and Chromium that I have seen the Speech Recognition part of the Web Speech API work with is Brave and Yandex. Yandex probably connects to a server in Russia to process the speech recognition. It does not do a good job. At least in English. At the moment Brave is returning a "Network" error. According to this [github Brave discussion](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3725) Brave would have to pay Google in order to get the speech to text service.

Here is some quick code that can be used to test if Speech Recognition works in a browser and display all the errors and events in the body. It only works with https protocol. It does not seem to work with codepen or jsfiddle.

```
var msg = document.body;
var cr = "<br />";
var event_list = ["onaudioend", "onaudiostart", "onend", "onerror", "onnomatch", "onresult", "onsoundend", "onsoundstart", "onspeechend", "onspeechstart", "onstart"];
var sr = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition || false;

if (sr) {
    var recognition = new sr();
    event_list.forEach(function(e) {
        recognition[e] = function() { 
            console.log(event); 
            var txt = event.type + ": ";
            if (event.results) txt += event.results[0][0].transcript;
            if (event.error) txt += event.error; // "not-allowed" usually is because of not using secure https protocol
            if (event.type == "end") 
                recognition.start(); // Start Recognition again
            msg.innerHTML += txt + cr;
        };  
    });
    recognition.start();
}
else {
    msg.innerHTML += "This browser does not support SpeechRecognition or webkitSpeechRecognition." + cr;
}
```

Comment: How does chromium perform speech recognition? Is it done by a library? If so which one? Is  it some internal work? Does it rely on a server for doing speech recognition?

Comment: @Stephan Google programmed Chrome and Chromium to use the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API). It uses javascript. It does contact a server that Google has setup. That is not on the front end though and Google does not really mention it.